# Prevent XSS but allow all characters?

Tags: php, xss

How can I prevent XSS but allow any characters to be used? Like I can post HTML code on a forum  like `<html><body><h1>Test</h1></html>`, but it would not be rendered in the browser as html? How can I do this so it does not convert the characters in PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent XSS with HTML/PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php)

Answer (score 2):

Pass a string through the [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function:

```
// Outputs HTML as literal characters
echo htmlspecialchars('<html><body><h1>Test</h1></html>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a string safe to output with [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) or [htmlspecialchars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).
htmlentities is more thorough, as it encodes all entities, while htrmlspecialchars only transforms bracket, quote and the ampersand characters.

For instance, it changes `<` into `&lt;`, which is displayed by the browser as a < symbol rather than being is interpreted as the start of an HTML tag.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting approach is [DOM](http://php.net/dom) + [Tidy](http://php.net/tidy) -  [Source](http://shiflett.org/blog/2007/mar/allowing-html-and-preventing-xss)